# Is it possible to enable WinRM in a Modern.ie VM or Vagrant Box by repackaging it with Packer?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, packer, winrm, modern.ie

There are these free like free beer virtual machines (VM) from Microsoft which one can download from [modern.ie](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/) and use for testing or whatever. And there is this nice [Gist on Github](https://gist.github.com/andreptb/57e388df5e881937e62a) which explains how to enable WinRM support on that VMs. Unfortunately this requires manual interaction with the VM after initial boot up ([step 2. in Gist](https://gist.github.com/andreptb/57e388df5e881937e62a#2-setup)). Is it possible to let [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) do this job using it´s builder type `virtualbox-ovf` ([VIRTUALBOX BUILDER (FROM AN OVF/OVA)](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox-ovf.html))? If it is possible can you provide some example code, please.

*Or asked another way*: How to create a Vagrant Box from an existing VirtualBox image (`.ova` file) or from an existing Vagrant Box (`.ovf`file) with Packer?

Comment: They have a contact email here: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/Microsoft/ perhaps worth getting in touch?

Comment: I've also opened an issue here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8671134/

Answer (score 0):

What you asked is described in Step 4

> 4. Package
>
> Since there's a lot of Windows specific configuration, you can include
>   the Vagrantfile in the package command so winrm and virtualbox
>   configuration get's default values when the repackaged is used for
>   other purposes. Remember to run the command in the same directory the
>   Vagrantfile resides:
>
> `$ vagrant package --output "yourboxname" --Vagrantfile Vagrantfile`
>
> After that you're all set!

once you complete step2 and 3, you will run step4 which recreate a vagrant box from the updated VM and you can re-use this box

> Or asked another way: How to create a Vagrant Box from an existing VirtualBox image (.ova file) or from an existing Vagrant Box (.ovffile) with Packer?

This is not possible, shortly speaking, packer creates Vagrant box from OS ISO distribution, not from existing VM

Comment: But Packer docs say this: ["This VirtualBox Packer builder is able to create VirtualBox virtual machines and export them in the OVF format, starting from an existing OVF/OVA (exported virtual machine image)."](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox-ovf.html) Note the **" starting from an existing OVF/OVA"**  part. Do I get something wrong?

Comment: ok looks like you're right - not sure whats the use case vs [vagrant package](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/package.html); anyway I have always considered `vagrant box repackage` as my option to recreate a vagrant box from existing VM initially created from vagrant

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to Windows modern.ie VM with ssh (Openssh service runs at startup). You'll have a very limited shell, but enough to call cmd.exe or powershell, and activate WinRM. On Windows 10 VM, you just have to change the network type to something not public. That's it.